# Keepliaved not loading IPv6 lvs rules on boot

Tags: keepalived, lvs

When starting Keepalived manually, it correctly populates LVS tables as seen by:

```
ipvsadm
```

However, when I boot the machine - only IPv4 rules are added.

If I restart the keepliaved server manually after the machine has booted, the IPv6 rules is added correctly again.

What could be wrong here, and how to fix it?